# iPhone has stopped working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Good morning(day/evening/night),

A while ago I installed iOS 6.0 beta on my iPhone. Since then I've been updating to the most recent version of iOS whenever it came out(iOS 6.0 Beta 4 being the last one). But this morning something weird happened.

When I woke up and tried to turn off the alarm, I was shocked by the fact that I had a Wi-Fi choosing screen. After clicking `Next` at the right side of the navigation bar, it went to a new screen and said "It may take a few minutes to activate your iPhone". After that it told me that iPhone couldn't be activated.

After connecting my iPhone to the Mac, I tried updating iOS, but iTunes said "The software on the iPhone has expired and must be updated to a newer version". But when I try to update from iTunes, it says that iPhone has the most recent version(6.0).

Starting Xcode and organizer showed me that iOS installed is `6.0 (10A5376e)`, which is iOS 6.0 Beta 4(now it's obvious that it's expired and should be updated). The question is: **How can I update to iOS 6.0 from iOS 6.0 Beta 4?**

Thanks,

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The question is off-topic here for the better part.

Comment: This is a question that belongs in Apple's developer forums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must download the iOS6 release version** and restore from iTunes with the `alt+restore` trick.

**Note that you will lose all your data if you don't have a backup.**

There is a way to do this though, without the need to restore and data will be preserved. This is by clicking the `alt+check for updates` instead of `alt+restore`. This is not what Apple recommends so I won't either, but if you don't have a backup and you don't want to loose your data seems like the only choice right now.